# AS3 function producing combinations of array, no duplicates

Tags: actionscript-3, combinations

This sounds like a duplicate question, as there are several questions similar to this, but they don't specifically ask *this* (or I just haven't found it! :) )
I have an array, this one has two distinct elements, "a" and "b", and a length of four total elements:

```
    var list:Array = ["a","a","b","b"];
```

I'm looking for all combinations, using **all** elements, no duplicates.
This should yield:

```
    aabb
    abab
    abba
    bbaa
    baba
    baab
```

Searching for a solution for this has given me results similar to these:

- a,b,ab,ba,aab,abb,aba, *etc*
  or
- **a** a **b** b, a **a** **b** b, **a** a b **b**, *etc*

Mind you, the application that would ultimately use this function would have two distinct elements, "a" and "b", and a length of 50 total elements:

```
    var list:Array = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a",
                      "a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a",
                      "a","a","a","a","a",
                      "b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",
                      "b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",
                      "b","b","b","b","b"]
```

...so a brute force solution like I used with aabb wouldn't be feasible.

Any help, especially using AS3 code, would be appreciated, even if it is simply pointing me to the right google search :)

Comment: It is **itertools.combinations** or **itertools.permutations** in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html So, you should google > **as3 combinations permutations**, there are results that seem relevant.

Comment: These are permutations of [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). A really fast technique is to first find all combinations of the multiset first, then subsequently use a standard `next_permutation` (like in c++) to operate on each combination. I published a package in R for doing these types of things. The source code for this task can be found [here](https://github.com/jwood000/RcppAlgos/blob/35d73b7fc9fefb2b39f1acf0cdda32f359cd5f52/src/CombinatoricsContainer.cpp#L538) (It's entirely in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript answer that might get you started: [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript/37580979#37580979) (they're both EcmaScript implementations so converting to ActionScript should only require minor changes)

It doesn't handle the uniqueness requirement, but it might point you in the right direction.

However, there are a few things you might need to consider first. I don't think it will be feasible to pre-compute all unique permutations upfront.

Based on [this answer about unique permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175621/distinct-permutations-of-the-word-toffee) it looks like there are `50! / 25! * 25! = 126,410,606,437,752` unique permutations for 25 a's and 25 b's.

To give an idea how large that number is: if each combination was 1 byte in memory (in practice it will be more than this) then that would be: `126410606437752 bytes = 126,410.6 gigabytes` in memory.

Plus, the algorithm for generating the permutations has complexity `O(n!)` - so it might take far too long, separate to memory constraints, to generate the list of permutations.